# "A larger" vs "larger" to describe the sample size of a study

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

I wrote a sentence: A study with a larger sample size is required to make more conclusive remarks.

Grammarly tells me it should be, "A study with larger sample size is required to make more conclusive remarks".

Is this true? My sentence sounds correct to me. If yes, why?

Comment: Your version sounds more correct to me (AmE speaker).

Comment: Don't expect software-based grammar checkers to teach you English. They're only really useful for flagging up ***possible "slip-ups"*** written by native speakers (who will have the confidence to ignore "false alarms"). The article is effectively optional in contexts like *He ordered breakfast and [**a**] coffee this morning, He moved into a house with [**a**] garden last month*. So far as I'm concerned those examples are syntactically much the same as yours, and it's really just a stylistic choice / idiomacy whether to include the article or not, not a matter of "grammatical rules" as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (& Rajah9) Thanks for your answers and for the extra examples that gave me more to think about! I will definitely be careful about relying on Grammarly too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammarly detects *size* as uncountable in your sentence, and suggests that the indefinite article is redundant with uncountable nouns.

I don't believe that *size* is uncountable here: you are identifying one of a number of different sizes (just as one may have more than sort of beer, or water, or bread). In this case, I concur with you that Grammarly has made a mistake. <s>It's only human.</s>

When I tried it, I said its suggestion to remove the article was wrong and flagged it as incorrect. Grammarly **now** flags the sentence **without** an article as incorrect, for me at least: "It appears that an article is missing before the word *larger.* Consider adding the article."

Comment: Thanks for clueing me in to the fact that I should read about uncountable and countable nouns to get a clearer understanding, and for the answer!